# How to fix strange usb serial problems in windows 10?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, serial-port

I have several issues with serial ports in windows 10. The first one is
"ie_Open - device already open" in real term, but I also can't open the port in any program.

Even uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it doesn't help.
Restarting the computer doesn't help.

I then tried to force install an FTDI driver for the USB serial port, which got stuck on the install I restarted and then the driver got stuck. So what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the USB root hub drivers, in fact this will probably solve a host of usb-serial problems. I was getting really connection problems, with ports getting stuck. I think uninstalling the root hub might reset registry errors that might be happening. I was also plugging in two separate devices with FTDI 230Q chipsets so that could have caused problems. Anyway the fix is to find all USB root hubs, uninstall then click on scan for devices:

[image]
Source: https://thegeekpage.com/fix-error-usb-device-descriptor-failure-in-windows-10-solved/

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this, as uninstalling the USB root hub didnt work for me.

I used a FTDI chip to communicate with the PC/MCU. It seems like because my MCU started sending data as soon as it was plugged into the USB port, the computer would get confused during the enumeration process.

I added a 3 seconds delay on the MCU before starting to send data to the com port (UART) on wake up/reset. And my issue was solved.